# how to link different page to a button in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

How to link a login component to the button in home page so that it would open up a login page in angular?

I have tried doing this,
i have to create a click to a login button as i have created it in myaccount-dropdown component
in my-account-dropdown.html

```
      <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
        <button (click)="navigateToLogin('login')">Login</button>
      </a>
```

in my-account-dropdown.ts

```
export class MyAccountDropdownComponent {
  isMenuOpen: boolean = false;

  toggleMenu(): void {
    this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  navigateToLogin(pagename: string):void {
  this.router.navigate([`${pagename}`]);
}
}
```

in app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/login/login.component'; // Replace with the actual login component

const routes: Routes = [
  // Other routes
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, // Replace with the actual login component
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

i have also made header component and footer component and have linked them as home page in app.component.html
now i want only login page to be shown up when click the button
when i click the button its just flickering also the login comes under the homepage where should i link it then?

Comment: According to **#3** of [this guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route), you need to define [`router-outlet`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) element in your template where you want to paint the content of the selected route. I don't see that part in the code above.

Comment: yeah, i have mentioned it in my app.component.html where header and footer components are also linked.
but i want this login page to be appeared seperately in new page without haeder and footer. to do so where to link this router outlet?

Comment: `router-outlet` has no connection with headers or footers. If you want to render a route, you have to use that specific element. Otherwise Angular has no way knowing where to render it.

Comment: First step would be to use valid HTML. Either it is a link, then use an `<a>`- Tag. or it is a button, then you use the `<button>` element. Nesting them is invalid and doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your my-account-dropdown.html file seems fine.
In  my-account-dropdown.ts file use function as below:-
navigateToLogin():void {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}

app-routing.module.ts file is also fine.

You need to update the structure of your project in app html and app.ts file as follow:-

App component.ts file:-
Initialize - routerChangeSubscription: Subscription | undefined;
Call a function in contructor - this.getRouterChangeSubscription();
Define above function-
getRouterChangeSubscription(): void {
    this.routerChangeSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((route: any) => {
      if (route instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (route.url === '/' || route.url === '/login') {
          this.isShow = false;
        }
        else {
          this.isShow = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
App component.html :-
<div *ngIf='this.show'>
    <app-header></app-header>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div *ngIf='this.show'>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>

when you visit login page then only login page UI will render ...Header and footer UI will get hide with this.show variable.
```